# Почему результат этих вычислений таков?

Tags: c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    ssize_t fsize = 2047;
    i = fsize - 2048*(fsize / 2048);
    printf("R: %d\n", i);


}
```

В результате i = 2047
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне математика подсказывает, что должно быть 0, но..

Comment: Целочисленное деление или с точкой?

Comment: Если делить на `2048.0`, то результат будет таки `0` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип `ssize_t` - целочисленный.

**Целочисленное** деление — это деление с отбрасыванием дробной части.

2047/2048 с отбрасыванием дробной части равно 0.

Дальше все очевидно?

Comment: О господи, точно, спасибо. Я недумая вырвал этот кусок кода из программы, как только с моей математикой совпадать не стал. Прошу прощения